# Evolution of minimization of surface tension

Tags: fluid-dynamics, variational-principle, surface-tension

What are governing equations (or/and variational principles) for evolution of a simply connected body of water in vacuum?

Initial state - for time $t=0$ we have a bounded simply connected set $\Omega$ containing water, for simplicity - macroscopic velocity is zero and macroscopic temperature is constant.

Comment: This question is a little vague as written, could you explain a bit more about what you mean?

Comment: sorry... I will describe the initial state - for time $t=0$ we have a bounded simply connected set $\Omega$ containing water, for simplicity local expectation value of temperature is constant and of velocity is zero..

Comment: Comments are liable to be deleted. Please amend the question itself using the `edit` button.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume that you have a well-defined interfacial energy $\gamma$ between water and "vacuum".

If there's only mechanics involved, Navier-Stokes equations with a boundary condition that the total stress along the normal $\vec n$ of the boundary (left hand side below) is normal and equal to the product of mean curvature $H$ and interfacial energy, along the normal:
$$
-p\vec{n} + 2\eta(\nabla v + \nabla v^T)\vec{n} = \gamma H \vec{n}
$$
where $p$ is the pressure, $\eta$ the dynamic viscosity and $v$ velocity.

Comment: Looks great, but do you think you could mention what the variables are? Like $p$ pressure, $\gamma$ surface tension, $v$ velocity... is $H$ mean surface curvature? I never took fluid dynamics so I'm not well-versed on it.